# How to store the database in the installation folder w/o user being able to access it? (C#)

Tags: c#, database, installation

I never see database files in the installation folders of random programs, yet they obviously have one. My question is how do they do it?

EDIT: My database can be either on SQL Server, MySql, or Access I'm not bothered, however I would like the client to not have to download SQL Server or any other programs in order to be able to use mine.

Comment: Some particular programs you have in mind? Why is it obvious that they use a database? What are you trying to achieve? What is your question?

Comment: My program is a encrypting engine (md5 sha1 etc.. for a uni project) 
I have a database which contains users, history of encryptions
I was referring to Games or Programs that keep a history of your actions mainly when i said it's obvious they have one 
I want to know if there is a way to make the database unreadable apart from during the execution of the program

Comment: OK, your edit about clients not having to download sql server etc. really makes a total mess out of the question. That should be the subject of a completely different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never see database files in the installation folders because installation folders are meant for programs, not for data. The data go into the appdata folders, such as "C:\Documents and Settings\User1\Application Data\Company1\Application1" or "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Company1\Application1" depending on your OS.

Comment: Ok thanks, how do i make my database location dynamic (in my connection string)?

Comment: If you are developing a winforms application, you can use `System.Windows.Forms.Application.UserAppDataPath`.

Comment: Thanks that's great, How do I install the database to app data folder?
I've got my setup project but i can't see to install the database where I need to. any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help with this. It might be worth posting a separate question about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the database file in Hidden Mode so that user can't see it until and unless he has `Show Hidden Files` option `true`

Or instead of placing database file along with exe you can place in dedicated application directory like `C:\users\username\appdata\yourapp\`

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of rendering the database unreadable by the user (except whilst executing the program)

Comment: Why don't you simply protect database with a password?

Comment: I like the idea of putting it here
C:\users\username\appdata\yourapp\
At the moment my link to database is :
Environnment.currentdirectory//mydatabase.mdb
How would I get C:\users\username\appdata\yourapp\ seeing as the username is dynamic?

Comment: If that's what you were thinking then why did you ask "how do they do it?" in the first place?

Comment: because i didn't know that that's how they did before

Answer (score 0):

> I never see database files in the installation folders of random programs yet they obliviously have one

If they are oblivious to database files then they don't need them. That is why you don't see them.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to store your own database as a flat XML file (for example, a plain .NET DataSet saved to file via DataSet.WriteXml ) then apply your own fixed encryption to that file. the key to encrypt/decrypt will be inside your program code and need never be altered. By storing your own data as XML you wont need a client. At the start of your program, Read and decrypt your datafile into memory, then save and encrypt out when needed.